# Getting C++ Variadic templates right

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I'm currently working on a project that needs an object that generates simple XML. I'm quite new to XML and still learning c++.
What I'm trying to achieve is a function that can be called like this in the code:

```
std::string xml = createXML("name", "attribute1", 10, "attribute2",
                            "stringForAttrib2");
```

After this line, the `xml` string should contain something like: `< parameter name="name" attribute1=10 attribute2="stringForAttrib2" />`

The function has to accept as many attributes as wanted and the name is not optional.
I tried something like this:

```
template<typename ...Attributes>
void XMLGenerator::createXML(std::string param_name, Attributes... attributes)
{
    std::ostringstream xmlString;
    xmlString << "<parameter name=\"" << param_name << "\" ";
    createXML(xmlString, attributes...);
    xmlString << "/>";
    m_xmlString << xmlString;
}

template<typename ...Attributes, typename DataType>
void XMLGenerator::createXML(std::ostringstream &xmlString,
                             std::string attribut_name, DataType data,
                             Attributes... attributes)
{
    xmlString << attribut_name << "=\"" << data << "\" ";
    createXML(xmlString, attributes...);
}

void XMLGenerator::addParameter(std::ostringstream &xmlString){ }
```

g++ doesn't like it:

> undefined reference to `void XMLGenerator::createXML< char const*, int, char const*, >char const*>(std::string, char const*, int, char const*, char const*)'

Why isn't the first `createXML` method called ?

Also if there's a simpler solution to my problem, I would be interested.

Comment: g++'s message suggests that the first function template is indeed called (used), but there's a linker error. Did you put all the template code in the header file?

Comment: Nop! forgot about that, just modified the code, now I get: multiple definition of `XMLGenerator::createXML(std::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)'

Comment: I fixed the previous problem. Now I get it to run, but get a segfault.

Comment: I think at this point, I'd need an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) / more information.

Comment: The interface is a bit weird, don't you think ? Passing in both attribute names and values all mixed up... I suggest you introduce a `template <typename T> struct XmlAttribute { std::string name; T value; };` element, and use that as parameter for the variadic call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here a [solution](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e55ca9b2f9e25900), the forward declaration are important and note the use of std::forward combines with universal references Ts&&  :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// =================================
// print_attribs parameter usage : ( os, name0, val0, ..., nameN, valN )
// name is char const* or std::string
// val can be anything compatible with os operator<<
// print_attribs is specialize for char const* and std::string values to enclose them with double quotes.

template < typename T, typename... Ts> void print_attribs( std::ostream & os, char const * name, T&& val, Ts&&... ts );
template < typename... Ts>             void print_attribs( std::ostream & os, char const * name, char const * val, Ts&&... ts );
template < typename... Ts>             void print_attribs( std::ostream & os, char const * name, std::string const & val, Ts&&... ts );

template < typename T, typename... Ts> void print_attribs( std::ostream & os, std::string const & name, T&& val, Ts&&... ts );
template < typename... Ts>             void print_attribs( std::ostream & os, std::string const & name, char const * val, Ts&&... ts );
template < typename... Ts>             void print_attribs( std::ostream & os, std::string const & name, std::string const & val, Ts&&... ts );

void print_attribs( std::ostream & os ) { }

template < typename... Ts>
void print_attribs( std::ostream & os, char const * name, char const * val, Ts&&... ts ) { 
    os << " " << name << "=\"" << val << "\"";
    print_attribs( os, std::forward<Ts>(ts)... );
}

template < typename... Ts>
void print_attribs( std::ostream & os, std::string const & name, char const * val, Ts&&... ts ) { 
    print_attribs( os, name.c_str(), val, std::forward<Ts>(ts)... );
}

template < typename... Ts>
void print_attribs( std::ostream & os, char const * name, std::string const & val, Ts&&... ts ) { 
    os << " " << name << "=\"" << val << "\"";
    print_attribs( os, std::forward<Ts>(ts)... );
}

template < typename... Ts>
void print_attribs( std::ostream & os, std::string const & name, std::string const & val, Ts&&... ts ) { 
    print_attribs( os, name.c_str(), val, std::forward<Ts>(ts)... );
}

template < typename T, typename... Ts>
void print_attribs( std::ostream & os, char const * name, T&& val, Ts&&... ts ) { 
    os << " " << name << "=" << std::forward<T>(val);
    print_attribs( os, std::forward<Ts>(ts)... );
}

template < typename T, typename... Ts>
void print_attribs( std::ostream & os, std::string const & name, T&& val, Ts&&... ts ) { 
    print_attribs( os, name.c_str(), std::forward<T>(val), std::forward<Ts>(ts)... );
}

template < typename... Ts>
void print( std::ostream & os, char const * name, Ts&&... ts ) {
    static_assert( sizeof...(ts) % 2 == 0, "arguments must be paired of string and value" );
    os << "<parameter name=\"" << name << "\"";
    print_attribs( os, std::forward<Ts>(ts)... );
    os << " />";
}

template < typename... Ts>
void print( std::ostream & os, std::string const & name, Ts&&... ts ) {
    static_assert( sizeof...(Ts) % 2 == 0, "Ts must be even, as they are pairs of name and value" );
    print( os, name.c_str(), std::forward<Ts>(ts)... );
}

int main() {
    auto endl = [] { std::cout << std::endl; };
    print( std::cout, "example", "foo", 10 ); endl();
    print( std::cout, "example", "foo", 10, "bar", "bare" ); endl();
    print( std::cout, "example", "foo", 10, "bar", 3.14f ); endl();
    print( std::cout, "example", "foo", 10, "bar", 3.14f, "bar", 3.14f ); endl();
    print( std::cout, "example", "foo", 10, "bar", "bare", "baz", 3.14f ); endl();
}
```

EDIT : Added static_assert of arguments count and char const* alternative to bypass needless std::string constructions.

Comment: Seems to be what I want, I'll need a bit of time to understand it properly though. Thanks !

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but is there a way to use your solution, without having to specify the "ostream" every time ? So the user only writes "print("example", "foo", 10);"